# PHP - Multiple conditions for if statement

Tags: php

I have two if statements which look something like this:

```
    //check if submit button is clicked and if the item is not expired
    if(isset($_POST['submit_bid']) && time() < strtotime($itemData[0]['exp_date']) ) 
    {
        //check if bid is lower than max bid or lower than start bid
        //if there is no bid $itemData[0]['max_bid'] is empty, should I check for that too?
        if($_POST['buy_bid'] <= $itemData[0]['max_bid'] || $_POST['buy_bid'] <= $itemData[0]['item_start']) 
        {
         //do stuff
        }else{
         //do stuff
        }

    }else{
     //do stuff
    }
```

I want to know if there is anything wrong with having 4, 5 or more conditions in the first `if`. I don't think the way I have it set up is right.

Comment: it seems ok. do you have any errors?

Comment: I might throw in a few extra spaces or break onto new lines to help keep it readable.

Comment: No errors. Just going over my code and want to clear up any questions I have and check if I can simplify my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you mean something like this?

```
 //check if submit button is clicked and if the item is not expired
 if((isset($_POST['submit_bid']) && time() < strtotime($itemData[0]['exp_date'])) || ($_POST['buy_bid'] <= $itemData[0]['max_bid'] || $_POST['buy_bid'] <= $itemData[0]['item_start']) ) 
 {
   // do stuff
 }
```

Comment: Yeah ... something like that. Is that too much to add to that `if` ?

Comment: @ciprian I wouldn't say thats too much to add to an `if` statement, however if you want more readable code it doesn't hurt to leave it the way you have it now, there is really no speed increase in either.